# Modify formatting-pattern to replace placeholders in string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, string-formatting, printf

I write currently a simple formatting function to replace some placeholders in a string.

```
var format = function (a, c) {
    return a.replace(/{ *([^} ]+) *}/g, function (b, a) {
        b = c;
        a.replace(/[^.|\[\]]+/g, function (a) {
            b = b[a];
        });
        return b;
    });
};
```

The syntax uses currently curly-bracket *notation* `{key}`, I try now to modify the `RegExp`-pattern to work with one percent instead `%key`.

```
var pattern = /{ *([^} ]+) *}/g;
```

I tried to just replace the parentheses `{}` with a percent `%`, but this still doesn't work properly.

```
var pattern = /% *([^% ]+) */g;
```

The **original** pattern **works** with the following conditions as **expected**:

```
var data = {
    obj: {
        foo: 'Foo',
        bar: 'Bar'
    },
    arr: ['Foo', 'Bar']
};

var objTest = '{obj.foo}, is not equal to {obj.bar}.'
format(objTest, data) // => 'Foo, is not equal to Bar.'

var arrTest = '{arr[0]}, is not equal to {arr[1]}.'
format(arrTest, data) // => 'Foo, is not equal to Bar.'
```

If we use my modified pattern it seems that the last character after each placeholder-replacement will be removed:

```
'%obj.foo, is not equal to %obj.bar.' // => 'undefined is not equal to Bar'
'%arr[0], is not equal to %arr[1]' // => 'undefined is not equal to Bar'
```

Any ideas how to modify the `pattern` to make it possible to use it with percentage `%` instead of curly-brackets `{}`?

Comment: Do you need to use %? How would you cope where % is a legitimate part of the string, e.g. `%obj.foo% is not 10% of %obj.bar%`?

Comment: So apparently, `,` should end an identifier. Then you could replace `[^% ]` with `[^%, ]`. But that means your replacement doesn't work with `obj["a,b"]`. You see, you'd need to actually parse JavaScript identifiers (with all their possible nesting), to make this work properly.

Comment: This library can be useful for reference or you can use it directly.
https://github.com/tarangkhandelwal/substitutor.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
var regex = /%([^\b]+)/g;
```

which means a `%` sign followed by a complete word. This excludes whitespace characters, underscores, etc.

If you instead want to be able to use those characters as well, you can write:

```
var regex = /%(\S+)/g;
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
var regex = /%([^\s]+)/g;
```

Comment: Yeah, looks good so far! However, there still remains one problem. If the placeholder is followed by a comma it seems not to work `%arr[0], // => undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your modified regex pattern does not know when to stop matching.  In the previous one it terminated at the following `}` symbol.

This is not an easy thing to fix as there is a myriad of possibilities that could be seen to end your format, here you have a piece of punctuation at the end of each replacement string, i.e. a full stop `%arr[1].` or comma `%obj.foo,`.

So to make this work in your case toy could replace `}` in the original pattern with `[\.,]` i.e.

```
/% *([^% ]+) *[\.,]/g
```

This will work, but now your replacement pattern needs to always be terminated with either a full stop or comma which i suspect is not exactly what you want.  Better to terminate with a know character such as % which would make your matching pattern `/% *([^% ]+) *%/g` and your format `%obj.foo%` and you can output a % by doubling up i.e. `%obj.bar%%%`